# How can I call a method defined in one CoffeeScript mixin from another mixin on the same object?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, mixins

I have a CoffeeScript object thas has two mixins included:

```
namespace 'S.Graphs', (exports) ->
  class exports.DocketEvents extends Module
    @extend Scatter
    @extend Axis

    name: 'DocketEvent'

    constructor: ({@litigation}) ->
      console.log("Building view of docket events for #{@litigation.name}")
```

How can I call a method defined in one mixin from another? I would expect that if I defined a method in one mixin, I could call it from the other:

```
window.Scatter =
  extended: ->
    @include

      dimensions: ->
        Justly.view.dimensions()
```

But I can't as this throws an exception that this.dimensions is not a function.

How come?

Also, if I don't define my mixin with `window.` as a prefix, I can't seem to use it as a mixin - what's the best way to resolve that?

Comment: Reason you need the `window.` prefix it that coffeescript wraps every file in an IIFE. You either need to export the class via a module system or attach it to the global object.

Comment: Any idea about calling one mixin's method from another mixin on the same object?

Comment: Hard to say from no more code than you've posted. Typically if I'm doing a mixin I'll use a helper function on the order of `mixin = (obj, mixes...) -> mixes.forEach((mix) -> Object.keys(mix).forEach((key) -> obj[key] = mix[key])); return obj`. Then I just call it with the class prototype as the first value and the mixin objects as the second. If the mixins are functions rather than objects than I use `OtherConstructor.apply(SomeClass.prototype, args)`

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not directly answer your question as asked, I believe it will give you a tool to fix your underlying problem. I had a situation crop up recently where I had to create several classes that each inherited from a google maps constructor. But in order to DRY my own code I wanted all of those classes to also inherit their common functionality from an abstract base class. Here's more or less what I came up with (simplified for example):

```
mixin = (obj, mixes...) ->
    mixes.forEach (mix) ->
        Object.keys(mix).forEach (key) -> obj[key] = mix[key]
    return obj

class MyBaseClass
    constructor: () ->
        #init some vars

    method1: () -> #do stuff
    method2: () -> #do stuff

class Signal extends google.maps.Marker
    constructor: () ->
        super()                            #adds google maps goodness
        MyBaseClass.apply(this, arguments) #inits the vars
        @type = 'signal'

    signalMethod1: () -> #do stuff

#add base class methods. Messing directly with class prototypes is considered by
#some to be something of an antipattern in coffeescript, but it achieves the 
#desired effect here.
mixin Signal.prototype, MyBaseClass.prototype
```

You may have to tweak the application order in the constructors of each of your derived classes (does the call to super come before or after applying the MyBaseClass constructor? what about the other constructor expressions?) but enables multiple inheritance. Multiple inheritance usually is more trouble than its worth but sometimes is the best solution.